# Select similar movies based on franchises

Tags: mysql

Let's say i have this table

| id | movie_id | franchise_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 15 |
| 1 | 24 | 15 |
| 1 | 25 | 15 |
| 1 | 26 | 16 |
| 1 | 23 | 16 |

One movie can have multiple franchises, so i need to get all movies with the same franchises. Like if i want to get all similar movies for the movie with id 23, i should get 24 25 26.

This query works, but i'm just wondering if this is the right way of doing it

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie_id FROM movies_franchises WHERE franchise_id IN (SELECT franchise_id FROM movies_franchises WHERE movie_id = 23) AND movie_id != 23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is fine, but you could also express this using a join:

```sql
SELECT m2.movie_id
FROM movies_franchises m1
INNER JOIN movies_franchises m2
    ON m2.franchise_id = m1.franchise_id
WHERE m1.movie_id = 23 AND m2.movie_id <> 23;
```